# Integrating Owasp CsrfGuard Token Injection with Spring Security

Tags: spring-security, csrf-protection, owasp

Is there a way to integrate the the OWASPS CsrfGuard Token Injection mechanism with the Spring Security ?

I want to use the CsrfGuard 3 ability to dynamically inject CSRF prevention tokens throughout the DOM currently loaded in the user's browser.

Comment: What exactly is the issue here? As far as I can tell, you can easily use CsrfGuard alongside Spring Security. What is the benefit you expect from integrating with Spring, what do you want from it on the Spring side?

Comment: Csrf can be enabled using the <csrf/> tag in security xml file. In such case the csrf token name and param as _csrf_param and _csrf_token. I want to use this [link](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/CSRFGuard_3_Installation)

Comment: To implement the feature of per request csrf token. Now CSRFGuard has its own way of generating token and the per page token generaton can configured using this [link](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/CSRFGuard_3_Configuration#Unique_Token_Per_Page). I was not able to figure out a way to integrate these two.